Muti Tree View Select and Binding on WPF
I am currently working on a project that involves a multi-tree view selection in a MVVM,WPF application using C#. The tree view supports functionalities such as Cut, Copy, Move, and Paste  between nodes. and support ,Expand, Collapse Here are some details of the project:
The tree view has a single root node that serves as the common root for the entire project.
The root node has permissions to add Node A or Node B.
Node A has permissions to add Node A or Node B.
Node B does not have permission to add any nodes.
I have implemented two interfaces, IWBSChild and IWBSParent, for the nodes. The DataContext is set in the code-behind of the MainWindow class.
However, I am encountering issues with binding. Specifically, I am unable to pass objects as intended to the AddCommand. I am unsure whether the problem lies in the binding process or if I am misunderstanding how the tree view operates.
For example:
When the selected object is the root node, there should be two context menu items for the user:
MenuItem 1: Header = "Create new Node A"
MenuItem 2: Header = "Create new Node B"
The AddCommand should execute correctly with the ViewModel corresponding to the selected object.
When the selected object is a Node A, there should be two context menu items for the user:
MenuItem 1: Header = "Create new Node A"
MenuItem 2: Header = "Create new Node B"
The AddCommand should execute correctly with the ViewModel corresponding to the selected object.
When the selected object is a Node B, there should be no Add functionality available.
my project source code here: https://github.com/NguyenVung2305/MultiTreeViewSelect.git.
I hope to get assistance or guidance on this master
get Exactly the way Binding on WPF

Don't post a link to your entire code base. [Edit] your post to include a [mre].

You should bind to the MultiSelectTreeView.SelectedItems to set the MenuItem.CommandParameter. Especially in a multi-select context. You probably want to execute bulk operations.
When registering the ContextMenu with the MultiSelectTreeView you have to use triggers to show and hide menu items based on the current context.
The current context should be the MenuItem.CommandParameter value and is evaluated by the ICommand.CanExecute method.
This way you can disable the MmenuItem that is not allowed to execute (for example the "Add" action for the BNodeItem). Then define a Trigger that collapses the disabled MenuItem (or show it if MenuItem.IsEnabled returns true).
The modifications are simple. Just add a CanExecuteAddCommand method to the RootNode and adjust the ExecuteAddCommand to use the command parameter:
RootNode.cs
class ROotNode : NodeItem
{
  public RootNode()
  {
    AddCommand = new RelayCommand<IEnumerable<object>>(CanExecuteCommand, ExecuteAddCommand);
  }

  private bool CanExecuteAddCommand(IEnumerable<object> commandParameter)
  {
    IEnumerable<NodeItem> selectedNodes = commandParameter.Cast<NodeItem>();

    // Because you want to disable and hide the "Add" menu item
    // when the context menu is opened with a BNodeItem
    // simply return false if the selected items collection contains a BNodeItem.
    return !selectedNodes.Any(node => node is BNodeItem);
  }

  public void ExecuteAddCommand(IEnumerable<object> commandParameter)
  {
    IEnumerable<NodeItem> selectedNodes = commandParameter.Cast<NodeItem>();

    // have 2 option if user select ANode=> Add Anode
    //if user select BNote=>Add Bnode

    foreach (NodeItem selectedNode in selectedNodes)
    {
      // Because of CanExecuteAddCommand the items are all ANodeItems (for this AddCommand)
      var aNodeItem = (ANodeItem)selectedNode;

      // TODO::Handle ANodeItem
    }
  }
}

Then fix the binding for the MenuItem.CommandParameter to use the the MultiSelectTreeView.SelectedItems property as source. And finally define a Style for the MenuItem which collapses the item when it is disabled by the ICommand.CanExecute implementation:
MainWindow.xaml
<Controls:MultiSelectTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MultiSelectTreeViewItem}">
      <!-- ... -->
    </Style>
  </Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

  <Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.ContextMenu>

    <!-- 
      The CommandParameter is always the same binding: the SelectedItems property. 
      Therefore, set it via the Style to avoid duplicate code.
    -->
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="Add"
                Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
      <MenuItem Header="Edit"
                Command="{Binding ModifyViewCmd}" />
      <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
      <MenuItem Header="Copy"
                Command="{Binding CutNodeCmd}" />
      <MenuItem Header="Cut"
                Command="{Binding CutNodeCmd}" />
      <MenuItem Header="Paste"
                Command="{Binding PasteNodeCmd}" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.ContextMenu>

  <Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
      <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.(Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.SelectedItems)}" />

      <!-- Hide all disabled MenuItems -->
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                  Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility"
                  Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  
    <!-- ... -->

  </Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.Resources>
</Controls:MultiSelectTreeView>


Thank you very much for sharing your solution. I have encountered an issue that I hope you can give me some guidance.
The solution works perfectly when all nodes share the same ContextMenu. However, when each node has a different ContextMenu, the CommandParameter sent to the command is null.
I would like to create a dynamic context menu that adjusts based on whether the node is a root node, an A node, or a B node.
Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Everything is already in my answer. Just extend the example by adding a CanExecute for each command. Then inspect the command parameter like I did. Return TRUE for every node type you want to have the command to appear in the context menu or FALSE to hide it. The trigger in the MenuItem style will toggle the visibility accordingly.
